# How do I plot the following graph in Matlab code?

Tags: matlab

How do I plot the following graph in Matlab code with same dot lines and continuous line as in the graph? What is the code?

[image]

The slant line is the $\eta=2 \xi+1$.

I am a beginner in matlab. Kindly help me with the above drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, that also shows my way of working with Matlab.

First, we define $\xi$ varying from $-1$ to $2$ and then compute $\eta_1(\xi)\equiv 2$ and $\eta_2(\xi) = 2\xi+1$.

```
xi=-1:0.1:2;
eta1 = 2*ones(size(xi));
eta2 = 2*xi + 1;
```

Now we have to find the intersection. We can do it based on the data, as the first point $\xi$ where $\eta_2(\xi)\ge \eta_1(\xi)$:

```
intersection_index = find(eta1 <= eta2, 1);
intersection_xi = xi(intersection_index);
```

Or, if we know that the intersection point is $\xi=0.5$, we can find its index as the index of the last point in the $\xi$-array such that $\xi \le 0.5$:

```
intersection_xi = 0.5;
intersection_index = find(xi<=intersection_xi, 1, 'last');
```

Now we can divide data into two parts and plot them:

```
f=figure;
ax=axes(f);
hold on;

pl_eta1_part1 = plot(ax, xi(1:intersection_index), eta1(1:intersection_index),'LineStyle','-');
pl_eta1_part2 = plot(ax, xi(intersection_index:end), eta1(intersection_index:end),'LineStyle','--');

set(pl_eta1_part2,'Color',get(pl_eta1_part1,'Color'));

pl_eta2_part1 = plot(ax, xi(1:intersection_index), eta2(1:intersection_index),'LineStyle','-');
pl_eta2_part2 = plot(ax, xi(intersection_index:end), eta2(intersection_index:end),'LineStyle','--');

set(pl_eta2_part2,'Color',get(pl_eta2_part1,'Color'));
```

Since Matlab normally uses a new color for a new plot, we manually set colors of second parts equal to the colors of first parts with

```
set(pl_eta1_part2,'Color',get(pl_eta1_part1,'Color'));
```

Another option is to provide the value of `Color` as an argument of the `plot` command, similar to the `LineStyle` option.

The resulting figure is

[image]

Comment: what is the figure in your program? Can you please show the graph

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I have updated the answer.

Comment: nice but on the blue line, the dot line part should be  for $x<1/2$ while continuous line part for $x>1/2$. Your figure just opposite in that case. Any how I am a begginer and your code is more general. Just help me, how do I add  another line $y=\frac{1}{2}x+2$ in the above figure additionally. Please help me

Comment: your prgram code "ax=figure(f)" says undefined

Comment: @M.A.SARKARThere is no ```ax=figure(f)``` in my code.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Just add ```plot(xi,0.5*xi+2);```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

\begin{align}
& \mathsf {xi=[-2:0.1:5];}\\  
&\mathsf{eta1=2*xi+1;}\\
&\mathsf{cnd=(xi<=2);  // \text{ Indicator function that's 1  iff xi <= 2, 0 otherwise}}\\
&\mathsf{eta2=cnd.*(2*xi+1) + (1-cnd).*5;}\\
&\mathsf{figure(1);clf;hold\, on;}\\
&\mathsf{plot(xi,eta1, '--');}\\
&\mathsf{plot(xi,eta2, '-');}
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: How did you get $eta2=cnd.*(2*xi+1) + (1-cnd).*5;$ ?